# pass sql query as data to highchart

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using asp.net in visual studio for a webAPI, in which I want to retrieve some data from the database and pass it in another object.

My js chart is already fetching the API data, so the query must feed it dynamically

For now, my query results in a single column with 14 rows of data (one per month and a previous and post year comparison), and my chart receives an array.

here's what I have

```
            public class MPreventivasAXEController : ApiController
            {

                public static void createCommand()
                {
                    ConnectionFactory db = new ConnectionFactory();
                    db.abrirConexao();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                    string sqlAbertas = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS mes" +
                                        "FROM WorkOrder WHERE workOrderSource = '02'" +
                                        "AND YEAR(workOrderDate)=2018" +
                                        "AND conclusionDate IS NULL" +
                                        "GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)";
                    cmd.Connection = db.conn;
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlAbertas;


                    SqlDataReader res = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int i = 0;
                    int[] obj = new int[] { };
                    while (res.Read())
                    {
                        int temp;

                        int.TryParse(res["mes"].ToString(), out temp);
                        obj[i] = temp;
                    }
                }

                Grafico grafico = new Grafico
                {
                    categories = new string[] {
                    "Média 2016"
                    , "Jan"
                    , "Fev"
                    , "Mar"
                    , "Abril"
                    , "Maio"
                    , "Jun"
                    , "Jul"
                    , "Ago"
                    , "Set"
                    , "Out"
                    , "Nov"
                    , "Dez"
                    , "Média 2017"
                },

                    series = new Serie[] {
                        new Serie
                        {
                            name = "Abertas"
                            , data = new int[] {
                                /* 3757, 3880, 3588, 4039, 3902, 4082, 3994, 3951, 4279, 3859, 3903, 3986, 3879, 3945 */
                            },
                            dataLabels = new DataLabels {
                                enabled = true,
                                rotation = -90,
                                color = "#FFFFFF",
                                align = "right",
                                y = 10
                            }
                        },
                        new Serie
                        {
                            name = "Executadas",
                            data = new int[]
                            { 3757, 3880, 3588, 4039, 3902, 4082, 3994, 3951, 4279, 3859, 3903, 3986, 3879, 3900 },
                                dataLabels = new DataLabels {
                                    enabled = true,
                                    rotation = -90,
                                    color = "#FFFFFF",
                                    align = "right",
                                    y = 10
                                }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

the `series` object will receive the query in its data parameter instead of the numbers array, but I can't seem to find a way to reference my query into that slot.

So what I really need is to substitute the static data I'm sending `data = 3757, 3880, 3588, 4039, 3902, 4082, 3994, 3951, 4279, 3859, 3903, 3986, 3879, 3945},` for my `obj[i] = temp`, which receives the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming that you are using C# Asp.net Framework, Web API.

```
public class MPreventivasAXEController : ApiController
{

    Grafico grafico = new Grafico
    {
        categories = new string[] {
        "Média 2016"
        , "Jan"
        , "Fev"
        , "Mar"
        , "Abril"
        , "Maio"
        , "Jun"
        , "Jul"
        , "Ago"
        , "Set"
        , "Out"
        , "Nov"
        , "Dez"
        , "Média 2017"
        },
        series = new Serie[] {
            new Serie
            {
                name = "Abertas",
                data = new int[] {},
                dataLabels = new DataLabels {
                    enabled = true,
                    rotation = -90,
                    color = "#FFFFFF",
                    align = "right",
                    y = 10
                }
            },
            new Serie
            {
                name = "Executadas",
                data = new int[] {},
                dataLabels = new DataLabels {
                    enabled = true,
                    rotation = -90,
                    color = "#FFFFFF",
                    align = "right",
                    y = 10
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public static void createCommand()
    {
        ConnectionFactory db = new ConnectionFactory();
        db.abrirConexao();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlAbertas = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS mes" +
                            "FROM WorkOrder WHERE workOrderSource = '02'" +
                            "AND YEAR(workOrderDate)=2018" +
                            "AND conclusionDate IS NULL" +
                            "GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)";
        cmd.Connection = db.conn;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlAbertas;


        SqlDataReader res = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int i = 0;
        List<int> obj = new List<int>();
        while (res.Read())
        {
            int temp;

            int.TryParse(res["mes"].ToString(), out temp);
            obj.Add( tmp )
        }

        grafico.series[0].data = obj.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, i think that you need bring more results for comparison. I've added data just to the first index of the series.

Maybe you should use List type. Its easier to handle, has less pain to learn when you comes from another programming language. You can parse/convert it to arrays, as i did.

**This article can help you about lists:**
https://www.learncs.org/en/Lists